# Ejecutable para ambas distribuciones Visual Studio

Tags: visual, visual-studio-2019, studio

tengo un mini programa que desearia ejecutarlo en otra PC(W7) y me sale un cartel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi pregunta es: que debo hacer? Estoy haciendo el programa en visual studio, no tengo ni idea de como funciona, todo lo hice a base de videos información y etc.
Tampoco se como dejarlo como ejecutable, lo publique con click derecho publicar y me dejo el proyecto en una carpeta, y yo en mi maquina (W10) si lo puedo ejecutar, en cambio en W7 no, me sale ese cartel.

Otra cosa que hice fue dejarlo como extraible con winrar pero me sigue saltando ese cartel, se podria incluir lo que pide cuando ejecuto el programa?
Probe con

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Y tambien me da error, tuviendo que borrar la carpeta .vs

El proyecto esta echo en Aplicación de Windows Forms de Visual Studio Community

Agradezco de ante mano la ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: El error pone que tienes que instalar .Net, has probado a decirle que si?

Comment: La idea es que no me lo pida y que me lo incluya, son muchos equipos con W7 y tengo q instalar manualmente uno por uno

Comment: necesitarias declarar permisos de administrador en el manifest aunque creo que eso no sería suficiente, eso ya sale de mi conocimiento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era que no estaba haciendo en Framework.Net sino en Core.Net, por eso no me estaba dejando y siempre me instalaba algo.